# Configuring Mojarra 2.1.X on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-indigo, mojarra

The User Library download from Properties/Project Facets/Java Server Faces only lists Apache and Mojarra 2.0.X options.  And setting up a user library manually, if I add `javax.faces-2.1.11.jar`, it doesn't error, puts the jar in the entry, then says `\jarfiles\jaf (missing)`.  So I see no way to use Mojarra 2.1.X.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to understand completely that what are you saying? But as much as I can I understood that "you want you use Mojarra 2.1.X" in your project. 
Now here is the thing You should mention the server that you are using.
If you are using glassfish 3.1.x then you have to replace your `javax.faces.jar` present in `/glassfish/modules` folder with `javax.faces-2.1.11.jar` as the glassfish built in jar `javax.faces.jar` enforce glassfish to use `Mojarra 2.1.6`.
Now if it is Tomcat then it is up to you that you have to add all jsf compulsory jars in your lib folder :) 
One last thing that if you are using anyother server which has built in support for JSF and you are unable to find How to replace your jar from that server or you have issue with admin access over that server then you can also upgrade JSF by placing the newer javax.faces.jar file in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and editing the `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file to add the following two new entries: `<class-loader delegate="false" /><property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />`.
Keep in mind that you are only enforce Web servers to use your desired jars not the application servers because many applications servers are giving built in support for JSF. So `Configuring Mojarra 2.1.X on Eclipse Indigo` is somehow wrong to ask.You have to ask that how should I use `Mojarra 2.1.x with my XXX server` because eclipse is only IDE and these things are SOMEHOW managed by IDE but only in case of Webservers.
Thanks :)